# Microsoft Fakes shim for generic method

Tags: c#, generics, microsoft-fakes

I'm failing to grok how to set up a shim for specific generic method. Here's the signature for the actual method:

```
public IEnumerable<TElement> ExecuteQuery<TElement>(TableQuery<TElement> query, TableRequestOptions requestOptions = null, OperationContext operationContext = null) where TElement : ITableEntity, new();
```

And here's how I'm currently trying (and failing) to configure the shim:

```
ShimCloudTable shimTable = new ShimCloudTable();
shimTable.ExecuteQueryOf1TableQueryOfM0TableRequestOptionsOperationContext<MyEntity> = (query, options, context) => {
    return new List<MyEntity>();
};
```

The compiler is just giving me a couple "Invalid expression term" errors, so obviously I'm missing something pretty basic here.

edit: here's the shim signature that is generated by MS Fakes:

```
public void ExecuteQueryOf1TableQueryOfM0TableRequestOptionsOperationContext<TElement>(FakesDelegates.Func<TableQuery<TElement>, TableRequestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TElement>> shim) where TElement : ITableEntity, new();
```

Comment: You're confusing me... `ExecuteQueryOf1TableQueryOfM0TableRequestOptionsOperationContext` looks wrong... Especially how you're example method is `ExecuteQuery`

Comment: That looks supercalifragilisticexpialidocious to me...

Comment: Yeah, that's the magic of Fakes. Not always pretty, but it gets the job done. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx

Comment: @elgonzo try obj-c :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I can't find any official docs that cover this, but the problem was pretty simple after all. I am used to convention Fakes uses for simple methods, where you just assign a Func to the shimmed method delegate you're interested in, like so:

```
shimAccount.CreateCloudTableClient = () => { return shimTableClient; };
```

When generics are involved, though, Fakes creates a method that takes a Func as an argument instead of directly exposing the delegate. So what I needed was:

```
shimTable.ExecuteQueryOf1TableQueryOfM0TableRequestOptionsOperationContext<MyEntity>((query, options, context) =>
{
    return new List<MyEntity>();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  I had a generic extension method with the following signature:

public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class

Was struggling for ages, but after I saw your answer I have overridden it by the following:

ShimQueryableExt.IncludeMultipleOf1IQueryableOfM0ExpressionOfFuncOfM0ObjectArray<PaymentQueue>((query, includes) => { return query; });

Cheers!